pnpm/action-setup self installer issue
I've been running pnpm/action-setup@v2 for awhile now, but I started getting this error.
Running self-installer...
   WARN  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pnpm error (ERR_INVALID_THIS). Will retry in 10 seconds. 2 retries left.
   WARN  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pnpm error (ERR_INVALID_THIS). Will retry in 1 minute. 1 retries left.
   ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pnpm: Value of "this" must be of type URLSearchParams
Error: Something went wrong, self-installer exits with code 1
Installation Completed!


Upgrading to pnpm/action-setup@v4 fixed this issue
https://github.com/pnpm/action-setup/issues/135#issuecomment-2206861174

Upgrading your pnpm/action-setup to v4 in the deployment config file will fix the issue.
- uses: pnpm/action-setup@v4
    with:
      version: 8

